# Having issues with accessing values from a SwiftyJSON block

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

So here is the JSON returned by my ALamofire query.

```
{
    "status": "",
    "minute": "5",
    "seconds": "54"
}
```

Below is the function which I'm using to process the returned JSON. I'm not able to extract the minute and second value from the JSON above. I'm specifically interested in the minute and second values.

```
func returnTime(){
    if let test22 = self.userdefaults.string(forKey: "fiveholdid"){
        Alamofire.request(ticketingDets,method:.post,parameters: ["command":"remaining","id":test22]).validate().responseString{
            responseData in
            switch responseData.result{

            case .success(let jJson):
               print(jJson)
                self.timerJSON = JSON(jJson)
                if let status =  self.timerJSON["status"].string{
                    //print("STATUS" + status)
                    if(status=="expired"){
                        print("In Timer Expired")
                        self.throwAlert(title: "RESERVATION", message: "Your Reservation has Expired. Please try again.", delay: 3.0)
                        self.userdefaults.removeObject(forKey: "fiveholdid")
                    }
                    }else{

                    var minute = self.timerJSON["minute"].stringValue
                    print(minute)
                    var second = self.timerJSON["seconds"].stringValue
                    print("second"+String(second))
                    var secondd = ""
                    if((second.characters.count) < 2){
                        var secondd = "0" + String(second)
                    }else{
                        var secondd = String(second)
                    }
                    self.timeremaining.text = String(minute)+":"+String(secondd)+" remaning"

                }

                //self.datesLabel.text = jJson

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: everthing coming back as nil/nonexistent

Answer (score 0):

So here was the answer:

```
        Alamofire.request(ticketingDets,method:.post,parameters: ["command":"remaining","id":test22]).validate().responseString{
```

to

```
    Alamofire.request(ticketingDets,method:.post,parameters: ["command":"remaining","id":test22]).validate().responseJSON{
```

so I had to tell AF that I was receiving JSON and not just a String...